# How do i convert a transparent .mov-file to an mp4 file overlayed on a background-image using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, alpha-channel, overlay

I'm trying to convert a mov file with the following specs:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'test.mov':
Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2012-10-09 13:34:01
Duration: 00:00:51.60, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 217433 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: prores (ap4h / 0x68347061), yuv444p10le, 1920x1080, 215844 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
        creation_time   : 2012-10-09 13:34:01
        handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
        timecode        : 01:00:00:00
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le (sowt / 0x74776F73), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
    Metadata:
        creation_time   : 2012-10-09 13:34:01
        handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
    Stream #0:2(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74)
    Metadata:
        creation_time   : 2012-10-09 13:42:30
        handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
        timecode        : 01:00:00:00
```

I want a background-image with that video on top of it and save it as an mp4-file. In the meantime the video has to be scaled and cropped 
I need a solution which can be automated and placed on a server, that is why i tried ffmpeg

This is wat have at the moment:

`ffmpeg -loop 1 -f image2 -i background.png -r 25 -an -vcodec libx264 -b:v 1500k -vf "movie=test.mov[movie];[movie]scale=max(552\, 420*iw/ih):-1[OUT1]; [OUT1]crop=552:420[OUT2]; [0][OUT2] overlay=0:0 [out]" -s 552x420 -y output.mp4`

The problem is, somehow, the transparency is lost, and the background is black, instead of the underlying image. When i try the same ffmpeg command with a transparent FLV as input, it works, but i would like it to work without having to convert al source files first to another format

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated !

This is my current ffmpeg configuration:

```
ffmpeg version 1.1.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
built on Mar  4 2013 11:19:29 with Apple clang version 4.1 (tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66) (based on LLVM 3.1svn)
configuration: --prefix=/opt/local --enable-swscale --enable-avfilter --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libmodplug --enable-libvpx --enable-libspeex --enable-libfreetype --mandir=/opt/local/share/man --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --cc=/usr/bin/clang --arch=x86_64 --enable-yasm --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-nonfree --enable-libfaac
    libavutil      52. 13.100 / 52. 13.100
    libavcodec     54. 86.100 / 54. 86.100
    libavformat    54. 59.106 / 54. 59.106
    libavdevice    54.  3.102 / 54.  3.102
    libavfilter     3. 32.100 /  3. 32.100
    libswscale      2.  1.103 /  2.  1.103
    libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
    libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100
```

**EDIT**

This is the complete console output for the command:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -f image2 -i background.jpg -r 25 -an -vframes 2500  -vcodec libx264 -b:v 1500k -vf "movie=test.mov[movie];[movie]scale=max(552\, 420*iw/ih):-1[OUT1]; [OUT1]crop=552:420[OUT2]; [0][OUT2] overlay=0:0 [out]" -s 552x420 -y output.mp4
ffmpeg version 1.1.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Mar  4 2013 11:19:29 with Apple clang version 4.1 (tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66) (based on LLVM 3.1svn)
  configuration: --prefix=/opt/local --enable-swscale --enable-avfilter --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libmodplug --enable-libvpx --enable-libspeex --enable-libfreetype --mandir=/opt/local/share/man --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --cc=/usr/bin/clang --arch=x86_64 --enable-yasm --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-nonfree --enable-libfaac
  libavutil      52. 13.100 / 52. 13.100
  libavcodec     54. 86.100 / 54. 86.100
  libavformat    54. 59.106 / 54. 59.106
  libavdevice    54.  3.102 / 54.  3.102
  libavfilter     3. 32.100 /  3. 32.100
  libswscale      2.  1.103 /  2.  1.103
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100
Input #0, image2, from 'background.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj444p, 1024x576, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
[libx264 @ 0x7fddc3813600] using cpu capabilities: none!
[libx264 @ 0x7fddc3813600] profile High, level 3.0
[libx264 @ 0x7fddc3813600] 264 - core 128 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2012 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=abr mbtree=1 bitrate=1500 ratetol=1.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf54.59.106
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 552x420, q=-1--1, 1500 kb/s, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg -> libx264)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame= 2500 fps= 53 q=32766.0 Lsize=    9772kB time=00:01:39.92 bitrate= 801.2kbits/s    
video:9742kB audio:0kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.309877%
[libx264 @ 0x7fddc3813600] frame I:10    Avg QP: 1.97  size: 58522
[libx264 @ 0x7fddc3813600] frame P:634   Avg QP: 4.19  size:  7889
[libx264 @ 0x7fddc3813600] frame B:1856  Avg QP: 7.63  size:  2364
[libx264 @ 0x7fddc3813600] consecutive B-frames:  1.0%  0.0%  0.1% 98.9%
[libx264 @ 0x7fddc3813600] mb I  I16..4: 47.6% 16.4% 36.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fddc3813600] mb P  I16..4:  0.1%  0.1%  0.3%  P16..4:  2.9%  2.9%  2.6%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:91.1%
[libx264 @ 0x7fddc3813600] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  2.3%  1.1%  1.1%  direct: 3.0%  skip:92.4%  L0:23.8% L1:24.1% BI:52.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fddc3813600] final ratefactor: -0.23
[libx264 @ 0x7fddc3813600] 8x8 transform intra:16.7% inter:26.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fddc3813600] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 65.5% 84.3% 83.9% inter: 5.8% 4.8% 3.8%
[libx264 @ 0x7fddc3813600] i16 v,h,dc,p: 60% 21%  8% 12%
[libx264 @ 0x7fddc3813600] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 26% 31%  9%  3%  5%  8%  6%  6%  5%
[libx264 @ 0x7fddc3813600] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 22% 27% 11%  4%  7%  9%  7%  6%  6%
[libx264 @ 0x7fddc3813600] i8c dc,h,v,p: 34% 43% 17%  7%
[libx264 @ 0x7fddc3813600] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fddc3813600] ref P L0: 61.2% 19.9% 10.0%  8.8%
[libx264 @ 0x7fddc3813600] ref B L0: 91.0%  7.3%  1.7%
[libx264 @ 0x7fddc3813600] ref B L1: 98.7%  1.3%
[libx264 @ 0x7fddc3813600] kb/s:798.01
```

Comment: No, it's fine as-is. Thanks for providing the output. I might look into this later!

Answer (score 3):

`ffmpeg` does not currently support ProRes alpha channels.  (This is an [open enhancement request](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/ticket/1728).)  If you can instead use the QuickTime Animation (RLE) codec (`qtrle`) for the overlay movie then that should work.